# Method overloading return types

Tags: c#

I would like to overload the return type of a function in C#.  In this function a string would be manipulated in a specific way depending on which method is called which I assumed would be determined by the signature of the method of which only the return type is different.

I am fairly new to C# and in Delphi I would have been able to do this (If I remember correctly) so open to suggestion on what would be the best practice here.

```
    public Class1 GetAppSettings()
    {
        Class1 result = new Class1();

        //  Code does something

        return result;
    }

    public Class2 GetAppSettings()
    {
        Class2 result = new Class2();

        //  Code does something

        return result;
    }
```

I am assuming the calling procedure will define what type of return type would be required.

Comment: See generics. You can do `GetAppSettings<Class1>()` and `GetAppSettings<Class2>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading on the return type is unfortunately not supported. Apparently the return type is not (and indeed can not be) considered for overloading. The compiler can only tell based on the arguments wich one you want.

However there is bunch of other ways:

**out parameters**. Usually those are only used for outputs if you need to hand additional values out of the function (like with `TryParse`). But I do think this should be compileable and allow overloading:

```
public void GetAppSettings(out Class1 output)
{
    Class1 result = new Class1();

    output = result;
}
```

Another way should be **extension Methods**, but those might be too limited. And after all you are writing those classes right now, so they are unnecessary. I only mention them for completeness.

And of course it could be that you never *wanted* different implementations to begin with (wich is a core focus of overloading), in wich case **generics** are the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Generics was the solution.  Learnt something new.